# How to cause an intentional restart of a single kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am testing a log previous command and for that I need a pod to restart.

I can get my pods using a command like

```sh
kubectl get pods -n $ns -l $label
```

Which shows that my pods did not restart so far. I want to test the command:

```sh
kubectl logs $podname -n $ns --previous=true
```

That command fails because my pod did not restart making the `--previous=true` switch meaningless.

I am aware of this command to restart pods when configuration changed:

```sh
kubectl rollout restart deployment myapp -n $ns
```

This does not restart the containers in a way that is meaningful for my log command test but rather terminates the old pods and creates new pods (which have a restart count of 0).

I tried various versions of exec to see if I can shut them down from within but most commands I would use are not found in that container:

```sh
kubectl exec $podname -n $ns -- shutdown
kubectl exec $podname -n $ns -- shutdown now
kubectl exec $podname -n $ns -- halt
kubectl exec $podname -n $ns -- poweroff
```

How can I use a `kubectl` command to forcefully restart the pod with it retaining its identity and the restart counter increasing by one so that my test log command has a previous instance to return the logs from.

EDIT:
Connecting to the pod is [well described](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/).

```sh
kubectl -n $ns exec --stdin --tty $podname -- /bin/bash
```

The process list shows only a handful running processes:

```sh
ls -1 /proc | grep -Eo "^[0-9]{1,5}$"
```

proc 1 seems to be the one running the pod.
`kill 1` does nothing, not even kill the proc with pid 1

I am still looking into this at the moment.

Comment: What about suiciding the container?. I think you can do it by 1. logging into the container itself 2. from underlying worker node 3. ephemeral container. I am not sure ephemeral containers would have the visibility/permission to do that.

Comment: @null how would I do that? Do you have the kubectl command at hand?

Comment: you can login to the running container using kubectl exec -it <POD-NAME> -c <CONTAINER-NAME> -it bash. for example: 'kubectl exec -it static-web -c web -- /bin/sh -c "kill -9 1"'. For more details, please refer to the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Comment: @null tried it just now - no effect, command not found

Comment: Try killing the main process of the pod which should be one of entrypoint or cmd directive in the Dockerfile or the pod manifest.

Comment: @johannes you may not have a shell on distroless image. Next option is, login to the Kubernetes worker node and kill the container process.

Comment: Check [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65157105/15537201). Not sure what kind of image you're using, but with `nginx` and changing it to `nginx:latest` (which are the same) gave the restart of the pod.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor no luck so far. I can log into the pod but I dant knowk it out from within

Comment: @Johannes What have you tried from suggestions above? E.g. simple pod with `nginx` image restarts after issuing `kill 1` command. However pod's identity remains the same.

Comment: @moonkotte I am trying everything and a couple of extra ideas. My pod is not an nginx pod. kill is not a general solution and may work in pods where the user is root. The only thing I did not try is accessing the nodes since that also does not sound like the general solution I am after. I do not doubt that nginx can restart using kill. Experimentally it did not work for mypod.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve your goal. I'll describe below most useful options.

### Crictl

Most correct and efficient way - restart the pod on container runtime level.

I tested this on Google Cloud Platform - GKE and minikube with `docker` driver.

You need to `ssh` into the worker node where the pod is running. Then find it's `POD ID`:

```
$ crictl ps
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED             STATE           NAME                ATTEMPT             POD ID
9863a993e0396       87a94228f133e       3 minutes ago       Running         nginx-3             2                   6d17dad8111bc
```

OR

```
$ crictl pods -s ready
POD ID              CREATED             STATE          NAME                    NAMESPACE       ATTEMPT         RUNTIME
6d17dad8111bc       About an hour ago   Ready          nginx-3                 default         2               (default)
```

Then stop it:

```
$ crictl stopp 6d17dad8111bc
Stopped sandbox 6d17dad8111bc
```

After some time, `kubelet` will start this pod again (with different POD ID in CRI, however kubernetes cluster treats this pod as the same):

```
$ crictl ps
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED             STATE               NAME                        ATTEMPT             POD ID
f5f0442841899       87a94228f133e       41 minutes ago      Running             nginx-3                     3                   b628e1499da41
```

This is how it looks in cluster:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-3                           1/1     Running   3          48m
```

Getting logs with `--previous=true` flag also confirmed it's the same POD for kubernetes.

### Kill process 1

It works with most images, however not always.

E.g. I tested on simple pod with `nginx` image:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx            1/1     Running   0          27h

$ kubectl exec -it nginx -- /bin/bash
root@nginx:/# kill 1
root@nginx:/# command terminated with exit code 137

$ kubectl get pods
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx            1/1     Running   1          27h
```

### Useful link:

- [Debugging Kubernetes nodes with crictl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/)

Comment: I want to realize a watchdog process that kills the POD if something goes wrong, so that it can cleanly restart. For that I need to kill the POD from within, so only the second solution remains. However, my POD does not die when I do "kill -9 1"